# Exponential of big O

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In Hildebrand's lecture notes on analytic number theory, I have that

$$\sum_{n\leq N} \log n = N(\log N -1) + 1/2\log N + c + O(1/N)$$

And notes directly jumps from here to this

$$n! = C\sqrt{n}n^ne^{-n}\left(1+O(1/n)\right)$$

I couldn't catch the reason of this jump. Taking exponent of first equality it should follow that (letting $C=e^c)$

$$n! = C\sqrt{n}n^ne^{-n}e^{O(1/n))}$$

But I cannot justify the jump here, is it something like that?

$$e^{O(1/n)} = C\sqrt{n}n^ne^{-n}O(1/n)$$

I'm really stuck here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\exp(O(1/n))\sim(1+O(1/n))$ is all that's going on.

Comment: Try using the Taylor expansion of e^x.

Comment: Thank you so much. It all makes sense now.